# PHP response ajax color

Tags: php, colors, response

I have one question. I have this in my send php form:

```
'message' => $response->itemAt('error')
```

I want change the color and size font of this **'error'** but its doesn't go.

I can't change the **'error'** to  *some error text* because he take from extern Url the Error text.

Pleas help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did u tried anything?

Comment: yes for ex. i make like this <h2 style="color:#000000;"> 'message' => $response->itemAt('error')</h2> and in different position i put this but nothing work

Comment: Show your full code

Comment: message' => $response->itemAt('error') is it string or any Php code?

Comment: if ($response->itemAt('status') == 'success') {
        exit(MailWizzApi_Json::encode(array(
            'status'    => 'success',
            'message'   => '<h2 class="t700" style="color:#ffffff;">My own success text</h2>',
        )));
    }
    
    // otherwise, the status is error
    exit(MailWizzApi_Json::encode(array(
        'status'    => 'error',
        'message'   => $response->itemAt('error')
    )));
}

Comment: This is an array u can print `<?=$yourArray["message"]?>`

Comment: Exit where? R u using ajax?

Comment: require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/setup.php';

// see if the request is made via ajax.    
$isAjaxRequest = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';

// and if it is and we have post values, then we can proceed in sending the subscriber.
if ($isAjaxRequest && !empty($_POST)) {

Comment: This on start of the php file

Comment: the success or error show not like div only like alert message.

Answer (score 0):

when display error message display it in paragraph and change paragraphs color.